# Discarding Files of Different Lengths

Tags: filtering, dataset

I have a set of imported CSV files stored under the variable name `data`. The imported files are of different lengths and I would like to be able to discard the ones below a certain length.

I believe that Mathematica has a `Select[]` function that might be right for this, but I haven't been able to manage it yet. My elementary attempt looks like this, but it returns a set of empty sets.

```
newdata = Table[Select[data[[i]], Length[data[[i]]] > 47], {i, 1, Length[data]}]
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does each entry of data the entire csv file as an unparsed string?, i.e. `data[[1]]` is like `"col1,col2,...\ndata11,data12,...\ndata21,data22,...\n..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can be used if the csv files are imported as strings.

`Select` automatically iterates over a `List` of `data`.

So given a data like this

```
data = RandomWord["CommonWords", 10]
```

The following will select the data of more than a certain length:

```
Select[data, StringLength[#] > 7 &]
```

---

If the data is already parsed like

```
data=Table[Table[RandomWord["CommonWords",5],RandomInteger[{10,20}]],{20}];
Dimensions /@ data
```

then you can use the following to select those with more than 15 rows of data

```
newdata=Select[data, Length[#]>15 &];
Dimensions /@ newdata
```